# How to save exact date time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a VB.Net Project and I want to save exact date time in my MSQL DB. But I am not able to capture the time along with the date.

Expected Behaviour: **In DB 12-03-2012 01:03:23**

Current Behaviour:  **In DB 12-03-2012 00:00:00**

Code Snippet Below:

```vb
Dim temp = System.DateTime.Now
Code(temp)

Public Sub Code(ByVal dte As DateTime)
    Dim strSQl As String = String.Format("Update tblTenant Set dte = '{0}' blablalbla", dte)
    Me._Inst.execSQL(strSQl)
End Sub
```

**EDIT** the column type in DB is DATETIME

Comment: What's the column type?

Comment: This is crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Pass the `DateTime` as a `DateTime` using SQL parameters.  That code is passing text and letting the DB Provider to work things out.

Comment: Added the column type of DB in EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your `execSQL()` method is built, but it is not normal or at all okay to substitute variable data directly into an SQL query string. That's a good way to get your program hacked. Instead, you need a mechanism to accept and send the data to the server separately. That often looks something like this:

```vb
Public Sub execSQL(ByVal SQL As String, Optional ByVal ParamArray QueryParameters() As MySqlParameter)
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection("connection string here"), _
          cmd As New MySqlCommand(SQL, cn)

        If QueryParameters IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each p As MySqlParameter In QueryParameters
                'This does NOT EVER do string manipulation to set the data into the query
                ' Instead, it's sent to the server in a separate data section, where the variables are setup.
                ' In this way, data stays separate from code, and any possibility of sql injection is prevented.
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p) 
            Next
        End If
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

and then you call it like this:

```vb
Public Sub Code(ByVal dte As DateTime)
    Dim strSQl As String = "Update tblTenant Set dte = @dte blablalbla"
    Dim dteParam As New MySqlParameter("@dte", MySqlDbType.DateTime)
    dteParam.Value = dte
    Me._Inst.execSQL(strSQl, dteParam)
End Sub
```

I've seen many cases where switching to query parameters also fixed a vexing formatting or syntax issue, enough so I believe using query parameters here will very likely solve the problem that prompted your question.

Comment: Are you suggesting that OP is maliciously injecting a date with no time in the query?

Comment: I understand the sql injection aspect, but seriously, is there a case where a parameterized query preserves date+time better than a string?

Comment: @djv I've seen many cases where switching to parameters fixed some odd formatting issue, such as the server running with an unexpected locale. Parameters are also generally faster, and they're just the _right_ way to handle this situation.

Comment: Your last comment is very important to the answer, which as it currently stands, seems like you are trying to help the OP to protect against hackers.

Comment: It's part of the answer now.

Answer (score -1):

Either your sql column type is [date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql) (you say it's not) or you aren't passing the full date and time to the query.

Double check the sql column type.

Then debug your `Code` method with an intermediate string to hold the datetime. Check that it has the time in it.

```vb
Public Sub Code(ByVal dte As DateTime)
    Dim dateString = dte.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    Dim strSQl As String = String.Format("Update tblTenant Set dte = '{0}' blablalbla", dateString)
End Sub
```

[image]

Now, if you have the correct type in the database, and your query is in fact

> Update tblTenant Set dte = '04-21-2017 11:04:41' blablalbla

but you still don't see the time in the database, you have a different problem.

Comment: do we need to put single quotes for date time too?

Comment: @Unbreakable of course. Best thing to do is look at the final query string before it's sent to the server. Even better, execute that query in SSMS if you can.